# Notpad++ colorizing for a particular file extension?

Tags: notepad++

For example how can I set Notpad++ to open .csl files as xml files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings->Style configurator...

Pick XML from the Language list and then add csl to the User ext. list.